# org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$DefaultViewInstanceFactory of jBoss 7.1.1.Final takes a huge amount of memory - possibly memory leak

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, memory-leaks, jboss7.x

We're having a Java EE application using JBoss 7.1.1.Final. After a busy day on the server it becomes obvious that we have a memory leak.

Having a look with Eclipse MAT on the heap dump provides us at least the class which seems to be the problem.

```
org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$DefaultViewInstanceFactory
```

One of the instances of this class is consistently growing. After one day the retained heap is at over 70MB.

We guess that it is a configuration/implementation problem on our side but we're not sure where to start searching.

We are thankful for every hint and we would provide as fast as possible all infos needed by you.

Thanks in advance

[image: Eclipse MAT Screenshot]

Comment: well it still contains 262K of Map$Entry

Answer (score 0):

It seems we were just running into this known issue in jBoss AS 7.1.1.Final.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-4675